# VisionOS ZStack views are always invisible

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos

As it is possible to look at the window "from the other side" the content is transparently visible through it even if there is a background in a volumetric window. Is there a way to disable this functionality?

### Example Code:

```swift
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ExampleView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
        
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            ImmersiveView()
        }
    }
}
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}
```

### Normal window view:

[image: Normal window view image]

### Window from the opposite side:

[image: Window from the opposite side image]

Comment: Window is transparent with a seemingly ultraThin Material